# Visor de archivos PDFs creado en Java

Tags: java, archivo, pdf

He creado un **visor de imágenes para leer PDFs** algo similar al de Adobe pero no sé porqué los PDFs de muchas páginas -los de 10 o más no los suele detectar, se pone en blanco aunque lea las páginas,- o los que tengan imágenes en COLOR no los lee y rellena todo de blanco.

En resumen, **los PDFs grandes no los detecta y si hay imágenes en ellos en color tampoco.** ¿Por qué?

Intentaré separar bien el código para que podáis probarlo.

**Código ArchivosVO:**

```
package VO;

public class ArchivosVO {
    private int idArchivos, actas_idActas;
    private byte[] Archivos;

    public ArchivosVO() {}

    public int getIdArchivos() {
        return idArchivos;
    }

    public void setIdArchivos(int idArchivos) {
        this.idArchivos = idArchivos;
    }

    public int getActas_idActas() {
        return actas_idActas;
    }

    public void setActas_idActas(int actas_idActas) {
        this.actas_idActas = actas_idActas;
    }

    public byte[] getArchivos() {
        return Archivos;
    }

    public void setArchivos(byte[] Archivos) {
        this.Archivos = Archivos;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ArchivosVO{" + "idArchivos=" + idArchivos + ", actas_idActas=" + actas_idActas + ", Archivos=" + Archivos + '}';
    }
}
```

**Visual - programa principal con Java Swing-:**

```
package Visual;

public class Visual extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private int numImg;

    //Contiene el archivo PDF en bytes de imagenes
    private ArrayList<ArchivosVO> ListaComponente;
    MiVisorPDF pn = new MiVisorPDF();
    ArchivosVO pl = new ArchivosVO();

    //Para mostrar el total de paginas
    private int paginas = -1;
    private int totalp = -1;

    private String ruta_archivo = "";
    int zoom = 0;

    public Visual() {
        initComponents();
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH); //Full screen.
    }

    private void button_abrirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        //Metodo para buscar y abrir el PDF
        JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(ruta_archivo);
        FileNameExtensionFilter fnef = new FileNameExtensionFilter("pdf", "pdf");
        jfc.setFileFilter(fnef);
        int se = jfc.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (se == 0) {
            ruta_archivo = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

            abrir_pdf(ruta_archivo);
            this.img.disminuir();
            this.img.disminuir();

        } else {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No selecciono");
        }
    }                                            

    private void button_antActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        if (ruta_archivo.trim().length() != 0) {
            this.numImg -= 1;
            if (paginas == 1) {
                paginas = totalp;
                label_pag.setText(String.valueOf("Pag. " + paginas));
            } else {
                paginas = paginas - 1;
                label_pag.setText(String.valueOf("Pag. " + paginas));
            }

            if (this.numImg < 0) {
                this.numImg = (this.ListaComponente.size() - 1);
            }
            ArchivosVO pi = new ArchivosVO();
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaComponente.size(); i++) {
                pi = ListaComponente.get(numImg);
                break;
            }
            //Con este metodo mostramos la imagen.
            this.img.setImagen(pi.getArchivos());
            adaptar_vista();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Abrir un documento PDF primero");
        }
    }                                          

    private void button_postActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        if (ruta_archivo.trim().length() != 0) {
            this.numImg += 1;
            if (paginas == totalp) {
                paginas = 1;
                label_pag.setText(String.valueOf("Pag. " + paginas));
            } else {
                paginas = paginas + 1;
                label_pag.setText(String.valueOf("Pag. " + paginas));
            }

            if (this.numImg >= this.ListaComponente.size()) {
                this.numImg = 0;
            }
            ArchivosVO pi = new ArchivosVO();
            for (int i = 0; i < ListaComponente.size(); i++) {
                pi = ListaComponente.get(numImg);
                break;
            }
            //Muestra la pagina que corresponde
            this.img.setImagen(pi.getArchivos());
            adaptar_vista();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Abrir un documento PDF primero");
        }
    }                                           

    private void button_aumentarzoomActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
        if (ruta_archivo.trim().length() != 0) {
            this.img.aumentar();
            zoom = zoom + 1;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Abrir un documento PDF primero");
        }
    }                                                   

    private void button_reducirzoomActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        if (ruta_archivo.trim().length() != 0) {
            this.img.disminuir();
            zoom = zoom - 1;
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Abrir un documento PDF primero");
        }
    }                                                  

    private void button_cerrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        System.exit(0);
    }                                             

    private void button_maximizarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }                                                

    /**
     * Método para abrir PDF.
     * @param url 
     */
    public void abrir_pdf(String url) {
        this.numImg = 0;
        this.ListaComponente = pn.leerPDF(url);
        //Guardamos todas las paginas en el ArrayList
        for (int i = 0; i < ListaComponente.size(); i++) {
            pl = ListaComponente.get(i);;
            this.img.setImagen(pl.getArchivos());
        }
        paginas = 1;
        label_pag.setText(String.valueOf("Pag. " + paginas));
        totalp = ListaComponente.size();
        //Titulo del pdf
        this.setTitle("Visor PDFJava; Total Paginas: " + String.valueOf(totalp));
        //Mostramos la primera pagina
        ArchivosVO pi = new ArchivosVO();
        pi = ListaComponente.get(0);
        this.img.setImagen(pi.getArchivos());
    }

    /**
     * Método adoptar el zoom a vista.
     */
    public void adaptar_vista() {
        if (zoom > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= zoom; i++) {
                this.img.aumentar();
            }
        }
        if (zoom < 0) {
            String z = String.valueOf(zoom);
            z = z.replace("-", "");
            int zz = Integer.parseInt(z);
            for (int j = 0; j <= zz; j++) {
                this.img.disminuir();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Código CuadroImagen - todas las funciones -:**

```
public class CuadroImagen extends JPanel implements Printable {
    private float zoom;
    public static int ancho, alto;
    private BufferedImage bufferImagen;
    private Image imagen, imagenAux;
    private boolean hayFoto = false;

    public CuadroImagen() {
        this.zoom = 0.0F;
        setBounds(0, 0, 595, 842);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void setImagen(byte[] vi) {
        this.zoom = 0.0F;
        try {
            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(vi);
            this.bufferImagen = ImageIO.read(in);
            this.imagen = this.bufferImagen;
            this.imagenAux = this.imagen;
            this.hayFoto = true;
            this.ancho = this.imagen.getWidth(this);
            this.alto = this.imagen.getHeight(this);
            resize();
            repaint();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (this.hayFoto) {
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2d.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.translate(-this.ancho / 2, -this.alto / 2);
            g2d.drawImage(this.imagenAux, 0, 0, this.ancho, this.alto, this);
            setOpaque(false);
        } else {
            setOpaque(true);
        }
        super.paintComponent(g2d);
    }

    public void aumentar() {
        this.zoom = ((float) (this.zoom + 0.1D));
        this.ancho = ((int) (this.imagen.getWidth(this) * (this.zoom + 1.0F)));
        this.alto = ((int) (this.imagen.getHeight(this) * (this.zoom + 1.0F)));
        this.imagenAux = this.imagen.getScaledInstance(this.ancho, this.alto, 16);
        resize();
        repaint();
    }

    public void disminuir() {
        this.zoom = ((float) (this.zoom - 0.1D));
        this.ancho = ((int) (this.imagen.getWidth(this) * (this.zoom + 1.0F)));
        this.alto = ((int) (this.imagen.getHeight(this) * (this.zoom + 1.0F)));
        this.imagenAux = this.imagen.getScaledInstance(this.ancho, this.alto, 16);
        resize();
        repaint();
    }

    public void resize() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.ancho, this.alto));
        resize(this.ancho, this.alto);
    }

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int indexPage)
            throws PrinterException {
        if (indexPage == 0) {
            g.clearRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.drawImage(this.imagen, 0, 0, (int) pf.getWidth(), (int) pf.getHeight(), this);
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    public void imprimir() {
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(this);
        PageFormat pageFormat = new PageFormat();
        pageFormat = job.pageDialog(pageFormat);
        if (job.printDialog()) {
            try {
                job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MiVisorPDF:**

```
public class MiVisorPDF {
    public ArrayList<ArchivosVO> leerPDF(String rutaPDF) {
        File file = new File(rutaPDF);
        byte[] bi = null;
        ArrayList<ArchivosVO> ar = new ArrayList<ArchivosVO>();
        try {
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
            FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
            PDFFile pdffile = new PDFFile(buf);

            int numpag = pdffile.getNumPages();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
            for (int i = 1; i <= numpag; i++) {
                PDFPage page = pdffile.getPage(i);
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, (int) page.getBBox().getWidth(), (int) page.getBBox().getHeight());
                Image img = page.getImage(rect.width*2, rect.height*2, rect, null, true, true);

                BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(rect.width*2, rect.height * 2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
                Graphics g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
                g.dispose();

                baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "PNG", baos);
                bi = baos.toByteArray();

                ArchivosVO po = new ArchivosVO();
                po.setIdArchivos(i);
                po.setArchivos(bi);
                ar.add(po);
            }
            baos.close();
            buf.clear();
            channel.close();
            raf.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return ar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

}
```

Os añado unas imágenes para que podáis ver la interfaz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error cuando abro un archivo problemático:**

```
run:
sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Unsupported color conversion request
    at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.readImage(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.produceImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:141)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Unsupported color conversion request
    at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.readImage(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.produceImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:141)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:269)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Unsupported color conversion request
```

**Otro error al intentar abrir un archivo de un mapa grande de España por ejemplo:**

```
run:

Expected 'xref' at start of table
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at Visual.Visual.abrir_pdf(Visual.java:296)
    at Visual.Visual.button_abrirActionPerformed(Visual.java:188)
    at Visual.Visual.access$300(Visual.java:11)
    at Visual.Visual$4.actionPerformed(Visual.java:100)
```

Ambos archivos problemáticos, en cualquier otro visor de PDFs conocido funciona.

Comment: Estas usando PDFFile , puedes añadir su información por favor?

Comment: Añado el error que me aparece cuando quiero abrir un archivo PDF problemático.

Comment: Sí, estoy usando PDFFile, en los imports tengo librerías tales como: import com.sun.pdfview.PDFFile;
import com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage;

Comment: @Jorgesys Completé con el comentario.